# Installing Oracle Database 11g Express Edition on Ubuntu

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I'm struggling to install Oracle 11g Express Edition on Ubuntu 14.04
I've followed every installations steps from the oracle manual, when i try to
run the /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure, it gives me this error

root@server:/home/nuno# /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure

### Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Configuration

Specify the HTTP port that will be used for Oracle Application Express [8080]:8090

Specify a port that will be used for the database listener [1521]:1521

/etc/init.d/oracle-xe: line 405: /bin/awk: Is a directory
Specify a password to be used for database accounts.  Note that the same
password will be used for SYS and SYSTEM.  Oracle recommends the use of 
different passwords for each database account.  This can be done after 
initial configuration:
Confirm the password:

Do you want Oracle Database 11g Express Edition to be started on boot (y/n) [y]:y

Starting Oracle Net Listener...touch: cannot touch '/var/lock/subsys/listener': No such file or directory
Done
Configuring database...
Database Configuration failed.  Look into /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/log for details

### This is the output of log file

CREATE OR REPLACE LIBRARY dbms_sumadv_lib AS '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib/libqsmashr.so';
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

BEGIN dbms_datapump_utl.replace_default_dir; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

commit
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

create or replace directory XMLDIR as '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/rdbms/xml'
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

DROP DIRECTORY ORACLE_OCM_CONFIG_DIR
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

DROP DIRECTORY ADMIN_DIR
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

DROP DIRECTORY WORK_DIR
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

BEGIN dbms_swrf_internal.cleanup_database(cleanup_local => FALSE); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

commit
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this too for a while.  I followed the instructions on this pages:

[detailed guide](http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.com/2012/05/installing-oracle-11g-r2-express.html)

[another detailed guide.](http://www2.hawaii.edu/~lipyeow/ics321/2015spr/installoracle11g.html)

A problem I ran into was that the `sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure` would fail towards the end.

I found, for me, that the `net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range=9000 65000` in the `/etc/sysctl.d/60-oracle.conf` config file of the walk through was causing the configuration program to not configure the last step. I figured out the config file was causing it to not properly load an oracle instance, which than through the ORA-01034.  So, I just changed it to `net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range=1 65000` left everything else the same and it worked no problem.

I think because the ports I was trying to use wasn't in the ip_local_port_range it was making it not connect.